# Delete based on column criteria

Tags: c#

I am trying to delete any rows where there is 0 or Null in the Checksum column.

I can only make the ode work if I have either:

```
completeDT_memo.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("dcChecksum") == "0").ToList().ForEach(row => row.Delete());
```

or:

```
completeDT_memo.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("dcChecksum") == null).ToList().ForEach(row => row.Delete());
```

If I try to make them both work, the script throws an exception.

Can you tell be best bay to make this work together.

Thanks

Comment: Post the code that throws the exception

Comment: The result of the where must be a boolean. So, perhaps you can try this: .Where(r => string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Field<string>("dcChecksum"))

Comment: please explain what is your enviroment, and add details about your error.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is, that the exception will be thrown, because you try to check `r.Field<string>("dcChecksum")` is equal `"0"`, while it is `null`. So you have the following to options to check first, whether `r.Field<string>("dcChecksum")` is `null`.

```
completeDT_memo.AsEnumerable().Where(r => string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Field<string>("dcChecksum"))).ToList().ForEach(row => row.Delete());
```

or

```
completeDT_memo.AsEnumerable().Where(r => (r.Field<string>("dcChecksum") == null) ? true : r.Field<string>("dcChecksum") == "0").ToList().ForEach(row => row.Delete());
```

Comment: Your second code here looks spot on. I will give it a try :), I will let you know how I go. Thanks